# Google+ share button

Tags: google, google-plus-one

My client is asking for a Google+ share button alongside the Facebook, Twitter, etc. ones. I don't have a Google+ invitation yet, but it seems from screenshots that Google+ has the concept of sharing a page; however, I'm not getting very far with searches, which instead turn up information on the [Google +1 button](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/).

> What's the situation? Is there a Google+ share button? Does it reuse the +1 button? Or the Google Buzz share button?

(As a subsidiary question, is there a sharer url? I'm not a fan of including dozens of external JavaScript files in nearly every page on the site).

Comment: @paulmorriss, thanks, but I've just received an invite from someone else so it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of selected answer on 26 July 2011, there was no way to accomplish this, but there is now. See my answer here [Google +1 something via a URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18466/google-1-something-via-a-url/18724#18724)

Yes, it is specifically possible now to create a Google+ post linking to a third-party site and save the URL for that site, and share with circles. All while on the third-party site.

Comment: So in short the answer is "It's merged with the Google+ button"? (On an aside: I'm signed up for the Google+ Button mailing list, and they didn't send anything through. Sigh).

Comment: @Peter Taylor Yes, that seems to be the case, "it is merged with the Google+ button". Only other suggestion I might make (sorry, not terribly useful) is to join the Google publisher buttons announcements group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-publisher-buttons and of course the forum  http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/ and +1 API on Google Code site https://code.google.com/apis/+1button/

Answer (score 4):

I find no sign of a Google+ share button in their help files. On Google+ itself there is a link "share" next to each post and a share button at the top of the page (which is now on Google reader too). I think your client is getting confused with the Google +1 button. It may be that there's one on the way, or it's available to a few beta testers, but it's not generally available.

Comment: @Ardesco suggested [Google's +1 documentation](http://www.google.com/+1/button/) in an edit to this answer (Ardesco: this would constitute a new answer to the question and you're welcome to post it for consideration)

Comment: @danlefree, thanks for the comment. I don't agree that it's worth posting as an answer, given that I link a very similar page in the question, unless he can point to some text which actually mentions Google+.

Comment: @paulmorriss, I don't think my client has heard of the Google +1 button. I think the reasoning is more likely to be "Google+ is supposed to be the new Facebook; we have a Facebook share button; so we need a Google+ share button too."

Comment: Sharing is really designed to share personal posts to members of your circles, for general stuff on the net the +1 button should be used.

Comment: @Ardesco, do you have any reference for the existence or not of a button which third-party sites can use to allow users to create a Google+ post linking to that third-party site and choose which circles to share it with? I.e. an analogue of the Facebook Like button.

Comment: @Peter Taylor I think this is what Google released two blog posts about yesterday. I wrote a description of it in response to a slightly different question here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18466/google-1-something-via-a-url/18724#18724  I think this will accomplish what you asked about i.e. using the +1 button to share posts specifically to your Google+ circles.